# node.js, mysql, datetime and time offset

Tags: mysql, node.js, timezone, mariadb

I have a connection to a mariadb instance using the mysql module for node:

Node module, mysql:
  "version": "2.5.3",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Felix Geisendörfer",
...

Node, version v0.12.0

I am using am using a connection pool to access mysql:

```
mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
  'host':'myhost',
  'port':'3306',
  'database':'mydb',
  'user':'root',
  'password':'mypass',
  'timezone':'utc'
});
```

In my database I have a datetime field in a table that is set as:
2015-06-11 09:25:43

However when I query this from the database the response is:
Thu Jun 11 2015 10:25:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

My question is why is GMT+0100 being applied to the response?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a fix but a work around.

After reading the date from the database, calling the '.toUTCString()' method returns the correct time.